# Correct way of using background-size for an image separator?

Tags: css, html, image, background-image, background-size

I need to have an hr turned into an image separator and I am using this code:

```
<hr class="sep">
```

and

```
hr.sep {
background-image: url(/core/skins/Ninja/divider.gif);
background-size: 80px 38px;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
visibility: initial;
height: 38px;
background-color: transparent;
```

Unfortunately, it just displays a massively stretched image, like so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEIka.png

What is the correct way of displaying the image so it appears like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6izqU.png

Comment: Still no luck fixing it, no idea why it doesn't display properly, even though all of the solutions are correct, technically. I'll post a working example once more: http://bbs.azimuth.ninja/ninja-talk/4/aaa-ask-azzy-anything/

Answer (score 4):

**Updated answer** *after OP comment*

just change your `background-size: 80px 38px;` to `background-size: auto 38px;` or `background-size:contain;`

you may need to **use** the **browsers vendors** to cross browser it

see **both** snippets working below with the **same result**:

### background-size:contain

```css
hr.sep {
  background-image: url(http://t2.ftcdn.net/jpg/00/20/03/43/400_F_20034366_DPxCA1ryMUc73AcDi3u0WU6HUX94i8Rl.jpg);
  background-size:contain;  
  -webkit-background-size: contain;
  -moz-background-size: contain;
  -o-background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  visibility: initial;
  height: 38px;
  background-color: transparent;
```

```html
<hr class="sep">
```

### background-size:auto 38px

```css
hr.sep {
  background-image: url(http://t2.ftcdn.net/jpg/00/20/03/43/400_F_20034366_DPxCA1ryMUc73AcDi3u0WU6HUX94i8Rl.jpg);
  background-size:auto 38px;  
  -webkit-background-size: auto 38px;
  -moz-background-size: auto 38px;
  -o-background-size: auto 38px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  visibility: initial;
  height: 38px;
  background-color: transparent;
```

```html
<hr class="sep">
```

More info about `background-size` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

Comment: Hmm, I like the idea, but it isn't working with Chrome "37.0.2062.124 m" have you tried this on a new version of the browser?

Comment: @StevenEllenStarar give me a minute I'll tested there

Comment: it works exactly the same on Chrome Version 37.0.2062.124 m and FF 32.0.3 (both latest versions)

Comment: Same Chrome version, but the snippet works as expected for me

Comment: Not sure if this is allowed but here's a working example of the problem: http://bbs.azimuth.ninja/ninja-talk/4/aaa-ask-azzy-anything/ it should look wrong like the image on chrome 37.

Comment: I see the problem, I just updated my answer, although the background-size:auto 38px should work since its working in the snippet above

Comment: I've tried both ways of updating the code, indeed your examples do work, however it is still causing the same problem on that link I gave, even with these changes. The doctype is html5, should the <hr> tags be closed?

Comment: Good to hear! It works in firefox, but for the life of me I can't figure out what would cause it to look wrong in my browser, I've even tried it in Linux on Chrome 37, and I get the same result. The <hr> part seems to jiggle a bit if I move the cursor near some elements on the page, so I wonder if it being caused by another element on the page.

Comment: come [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62335/correct-way-of-using-background-size-for-an-image-separator) to chat, so I can help you better

Comment: Love to, I just need a 20 repute to be able to! Hang on a moment, I'll see what I can do...

Comment: Just trying to get the chatroom to believe that, it still tells me I'm stuck with less than 20.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62338/discussion-between-steven-ellen-starar-and-dippas).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
background-size: contain;
```

that should do the trick.
The `contain` keyword makes the browser adjust both height and width proportional to fit inside the tag.

Comment: Although the code is appreciated, it should always have an accompanying explanation. This doesn't have to be long, something the length of this comment is fine, but it *is* needed (mostly to keep you away from the automatic flagging system).

Comment: I tried contain as well and it has no effect on this issue, unfortunately, and I agree it too should work.

Comment: Make sure your html document is html5 as this tag is new to html5 and css3 (the first line of the document bust be only `<!DOCTYPE html>` for html5) and make sure every tag is properly closed.

Comment: As far as I can see, in your website, after some testing with chrome tools, i'm able to tell you it is stuck rendering the animated gif. If you change the image to a static one, it seems to render just perfect. Try this: Either shrink the animated gif to the size you whant to use (not shure if it works); or change it to a static image.

Answer (score -2):

it should be

```
background-size: 0 38px;
```

Comment: oh! my bad! i missed out the question with background-position, yes it is true